# Old sci-fi movie where snake like thing leaves head crushed

Tags: story-identification

I've got an image of an old sci-fi movie stuck in my head but I can't quite place it.  What I remember:

In a bedroom someone lies on a bed.  We see some thin, snake-like tendrils exit the person's ear, after which the person's head crushes in, as if hollow, but not in a super gory way.

I believe it may have been in color, but my memory is shaky on that.  It's definitely older, at least from the 1980's if not older.  It's an American production, in English.  I believe I would have seen it on TV between 1995 to 2005, maybe on the SyFy channel but unsure.

Initially I thought it was [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers_(1978_film)), but the Wiki for all three film adaptations don't read like how I remember it.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the 1993 version of Body Snatchers; https://media3.giphy.com/media/9raO2ZAjmSmKyGnjRQ/source.gif

Comment: @Valorum it's looks similar, but not quite the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that one possibility could be *Strange Invaders* (1983).

It had scenes similar but not identical to what you describe.  Glowing blue orbs of energy leave the bodies of humans, including sleeping ones, and the human bodies shrivel up like deflating balloons.